# Can code distinguish between click on info item and pin icon in MapKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit, action

Is it possible to create different actions for the info item (e.g. label / URL) and the pin icon in a map view? When the info item is clicked I want the app to visit the website, and when the pin icon is clicked I want the app to do something else. However I can only get one kind of action triggered whichever is clicked on.

[image]

Comment: Please show us the relevant portions of your code.

Comment: Make the title and question clearer, and also render the example image rather than merely link to it